# How can I programmatically determine the path of depenency jar within the code of project using the jar?

Tags: java, dependencies

I have two java projects: ProjectA and ProjectB. ProjectA has been compiled into a jar and set as a dependency of ProjectB. How can I programmatically determine the path of ProjectA.jar within the code of ProjectB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `foo` is an instance of a class from `ProjectA` :

```
foo.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
```

Or assuming that `Foo` is a class from `ProjectA` :

```
Foo.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
```

should give you the location of the jar.

Comment: Thank you sir! Works like a charm :)